# How do I allow php files to be loaded with different extension?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have some PHP files like `index.php`, `contact.php`, etc.

I want to name the files with the extension `.blah` (i.e, `index.blah`, `contact.blah`, etc. )

Is there something I can add to `.htaccess` to get them to load properly?

Comment: You can try an AddHandler and/or AddType. I.e.: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
AddHandler x-httpd-php .php .htm .html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at your `httpd.conf` to see how [mime type handling](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html) is done for `.php` files, and simply do the same thing for `.blah`, or use [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html) to change urls ending in `.blah` to internal redirects to `.php` through an `.htaccess` file. Either way, Apache's documentation is going to have all the details.